# Getting width & height of an image with filereader

Tags: javascript, dom, filereader

I am building an image resize/crop, and I'd like to show a live preview after they've edited it in a modal (bootstrap). This *should* work, I believe, but I just get 0 in console.log. This requires feeding the width and the height of the original image into another script (which I'll do after, just need them in console.log/a variable for now)

```
function doProfilePictureChangeEdit(e) {
    var files = document.getElementById('fileupload').files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        document.getElementById('imgresizepreview').src = theFile.target.result;

        document.getElementById('profilepicturepreview').src = theFile.target.result;
      }
    );
    reader.readAsDataURL(files);
    var imagepreview = document.getElementById('imgresizepreview');
    console.log(imagepreview.offsetWidth);
    $('img#imgresizepreview').imgAreaSelect({
        handles: true,
        enable: true,
        aspectRatio: "1:1",
        onSelectEnd: preview
    });
    $('#resizeprofilepicturemodal').modal('show');
    };
```

Comment: You can use an EXIF library if your images are relatively big (>500 KB). Then you just read the EXIF header that has a tag with width and height.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You have to wait for the image to load. Try handling the element inside `.onload`.

I've also simplified the process of setting the source of the two elements to how you should be doing it (with jQuery).

```
reader.onload = (function(theFile) { 
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = theFile.target.result;

    image.onload = function() {
        // access image size here 
        console.log(this.width);

        $('#imgresizepreview, #profilepicturepreview').attr('src', this.src);
    };
});
```

Comment: Great, thanks very much. I was under the misinformed impression that the files would of loaded with the readAsDataURL call.

Comment: `reader.onload` is called when the file system is finished reading the file from the hardrive. `image.onload` is called essentially when essentially the image object has buffered the image data in browser. I see how you could have misinterpreted the onload functions; glad to have help though.

Comment: Note: This works only when you use "reader.readAsDataURL". With "reader.readAsBinaryString" you have to go a different way.

Comment: @BennyNeugebauer which way? Provide some details or link to example.

Comment: You eventually need to get to a data uri from the image contents, so using `.readAsBinaryString()` is pointless.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst It isn't pointless if you send the same binary string to server (file uploads). using `readAsBinaryString()` is significantly faster than creating it manually in javascript from data URL.

Comment: This is giving me 250 in console every time. No matter what is size of image.

Comment: @SunilPachlangia: Are you displaying the image somewhere? Then the 250 px is the width of the displayed image. When setting the `src` of a newly created image ( `myPreviewImage = new Image()` ), then you get the correct dimensions.

Comment: I am using readAsArrayBuffer. 
How can I get the image width in such case?

I'm now getting the following error: 
`[object%20ArrayBuffer]:1 GET http://localhost/[object%20ArrayBuffer] 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 35):

For me the solution of Austin didn't work, so I present the one worked for me:

```
var reader = new FileReader;

reader.onload = function() {
    var image = new Image();

    image.src = reader.result;

    image.onload = function() {
        alert(image.width);
    };

};

reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
```

And if you find that assignment `image.src = reader.result;` takes place after image.onload a bit wired, I think so too.

Comment: It is not wired that image loading is asynchronous. All data in src must be decoded, if the src is a link it must be loaded and decoded to image, if base64 also. So it's quite natural :-)

Answer (score 4):

```js
fileChangeEventHeader(fileInput) {
    const oFReader = new FileReader();
    oFReader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.target.files[0]);
    oFReader.onload = (event: any) => {
      var image = new Image();
      image.src = event.target.result;
      image.onload = function () {
        console.log(`width : ${image.width} px`, `height: ${image.height} px`);
      };
    };
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" name="profile_img" accept="image/*" (change)="fileChangeEventHeader($event)"
                  class="input-file">
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer inspired by Austin Brunkhorst with a callback for ascertaining image size in case you want to reuse the function elsewhere in your code.

`fileControl` is assumed to be a jQuery element.

```
function didUploadImage(fileControl) {      
   // Render image if file exists.
   var domFileControl = fileControl[0];
   if (domFileControl.files && domFileControl.files[0]) {
      // Get first file.
      var firstFile = domFileControl.files[0];

      // Create reader.
      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Notify parent when image read.
      reader.onload = function(e) {
         // Get image URL.
         var imageURL = reader.result;

        // Get image size for image.
        getImageSize(imageURL, function(imageWidth, imageHeight) {
            // Do stuff here.
        });
      };

      // Read image from hard disk.
      reader.readAsDataURL(firstFile);

      // Print status.
      console.log("Uploaded image: " + firstFile.name);
   }
}


function getImageSize(imageURL, callback) {      
   // Create image object to ascertain dimensions.
   var image = new Image();

   // Get image data when loaded.
   image.onload = function() {      
      // No callback? Show error.
      if (!callback) {
         console.log("Error getting image size: no callback. Image URL: " + imageURL);

      // Yes, invoke callback with image size.
      } else {
         callback(this.naturalWidth, this.naturalHeight);
      }
   }

   // Load image.
   image.src = imageURL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the way I have for AngularJS

```html
          fileReader.readAsDataUrl($scope.file, $scope).then(function(result) {
               var image = new Image();
               image.src = result;
               image.onload = function() {
                    console.log(this.width);
               };
               $scope.imageSrc = result; //all I wanted was to find the width and height


          });
```