# javascript filereader undefined width

Tags: javascript, filereader

I'm having (probably) easy issue to fix but can't figure it out myself.
Basucally my `reader.width` and `reader.height` keep saying undefined :/.. everything else works as supposed to

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt, selector) {

    var f = evt.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
    return function(e) {
        var imgW = reader.width;
        var imgH = reader.height;
        console.debug("width: "+imgW); // undefined
        console.debug("height: "+imgH); // undefined
        var thumbHtml = ['<span><img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                        '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/></span>'].join('');
        $(selector).parent().siblings('.previewThumb').html(thumbHtml);
        $(selector).parent().siblings('.previewThumb').removeClass('hidden')

    };
    })(f);

    // Read in the image file as a data URL.
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    $(selector).siblings('.list').html('<span>'+escape(f.name)+'</span></span>');
}
```

I tried also`e.width` and `theFile.width` - all of them return undefined  :/

I tried to google but according to everything I have read reader.width should work

Appreciate the help

Cheers,
Tom

Comment: I dont think FileReader has a `width` property. Have you checked this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491193/getting-width-height-of-an-image-with-filereader

Comment: yes, that's what I was referencing on... I thought it would work but it just doesnt :(

Comment: you need to create an `Image` and set the file contents as the image source. and then read the image's width.

Comment: ohh ok, shall I do it inside  the reader.onload ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FileReader` itself doesnt have a `width` propery. The result from it contains only the raw image data. This has to be loaded as an `Image` before you can read the width. So you'd need to onload handlers 1) for the file to load 2) for the image to load.

Try something like this

```
function handleFileSelect(evt, selector) {

    var f = evt.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) { 
        // at this point we have the raw data. now we 
        // create an image out of it
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = e.target.result;

        image.onload = function() {
          // now we have the image.
          var imgW = image.width;
          var imgH = image.height;
          console.debug("width: "+imgW);
          console.debug("height: "+imgH);

          // we can insert image directly into DOM
          var thumb = $(image).addClass("thumb");
          $(selector).parent().siblings('.previewThumb').empty().append(thumb);
          $(selector).parent().siblings('.previewThumb').removeClass('hidden');
        };
    };

    // Read in the image file as a data URL.
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    $(selector).siblings('.list').html('<span>'+escape(f.name)+'</span></span>');
}
```