# Empty images when resizing images using canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm developing an image resizer for files from input field with multiple files.

The files are first added to an array of Json objects, because i use that array in my webapp to add, remove and rearrange objects.

My problem is that Firefox and IE11 both presents empty images when traversing trough the filelist, and I can't figure out what is going wrong, and i neither has figured out a workaround for Firefox and IE. Chrome resizes and show the images ok.

I have tried two diferent methods. A serial function traversing trough the files array, and a asyncronous read-resize-show function. Both have the same problem with empty images.

The HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
  <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" onChange="showFile(this)" multiple>
  <input type="button" value="Show one by one" onClick="showPicturesSerial(dataArray,0)">
  <input type="button" value="Show asyncronous" onClick="showPicturesAsync(dataArray)">
  <div id="imageListSer" style="width:auto;min-height:150px;border:1px solid black;"></div>
  <div id="imageListAsn" style="width:auto;min-height:150px;border:1px solid black;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript is:

```
dataArray=new Array();
showFile=function(obj){
    for(i=0;i<obj.files.length;i++){
        dataArray[i]={
            file:obj.files[i],
            data:{
                name:obj.files[i].name,
                size:obj.files[i].size,
                type:obj.files[i].type
                // Add more values
            }
        }
    }
}
showPicturesSerial=function(files,i){
    var imageListSer=document.querySelector("#imageListSer");
    if(i==0)imageListSer.innerHTML="";
    isPic=/^image\//
    if(i<files.length&&isPic.test(files[i].file.type)){
        var file=files[i].file;
        var reader=new FileReader();
        reader.onerror=function(error) {
             console.log ("error",error);
            i++;
            setTimeout(showPicture(files,i),999999);
        }
        reader.onload=function(e) {
            var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
            var tImg=document.createElement("img");
            var src;
            src=e.target.result;
            tImg.src=src;
            var MAX_WIDTH=150;
            var MAX_HEIGHT=150;
            var width=tImg.width;
            var height=tImg.height;

            if (width > height) {
                if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                    height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                    width=MAX_WIDTH;
                }
            } else {
                if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                    width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                    height=MAX_HEIGHT;
                }
            }
            canvas.width=width;
            canvas.height=height;
            var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(tImg, 0, 0, width, height);
            var img=document.createElement("img");
            img.src=canvas.toDataURL();
            var div=document.createElement("div");
            div.style.display="inline-block";
            div.appendChild(img)
            div.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(file.name));
            div.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(file.type));
            imageListSer.appendChild(div);
            console.log("finished:",file.name);
            i++;
            return showPicturesSerial(files,i);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
function showPicturesAsync(files) {
    var imageListAsn=document.querySelector("#imageListAsn")  
    for (var i=0; i < files.length; i++) {
      if(i==0)imageListAsn.innerHTML="";
        isPic=/^image\//
        if(!isPic.test(files[i].file.type))return;
        var file=files[i].file;
        if (!/^image\//.test(file.type)) {continue;}
        var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
        var img=document.createElement("img");
        var div=document.createElement("div");
        div.style.display="inline-block";
        div.appendChild(img);
        div.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(file.name));
        div.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(file.type));
        imageListAsn.appendChild(div);
        var reader=new FileReader();
        reader.onerror=function(error) {
            console.log ("error",error);
        }
        reader.onload=(function(aImg) { return function(e) {
                var bImg=document.createElement("img");
                var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
                bImg.src=e.target.result;
                var MAX_WIDTH=150;
                var MAX_HEIGHT=150;
                var width=bImg.width;
                var height=bImg.height;
                if (width > height) {
                    if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                        height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                        width=MAX_WIDTH;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                        width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                        height=MAX_HEIGHT;
                    }
                }
                canvas.width=width;
                canvas.height=height;
                var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.drawImage(bImg, 0, 0, width, height);
                aImg.src=canvas.toDataURL();
                console.log("finished:",i);
            }; 
        })(img);
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
```

I hope someone can figure out this problem.

Comment: The problem seems to be related to cpu power and ram. Resizing via FileReader and canvas is pretty intensive, and because of the asyncronous behavior of FileReader.onload, both ff and ie can't cope with it. Chrome and maybe Opera(not tried) is the only browsers who do it correct.

Comment: No, the problem is more that you don't wait for the images `bImg` and `tImg`  has loaded before you draw it to the canvas.

Comment: @Kaiido is correct. And this is how you wait for the image to be loaded: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15491261

Comment: Thanks a lot to Kaiido and Will. The image.onload solved the problem.