# ReactJS onClick not working in Firefox but works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, firefox

I am trying to create a ReactJS-App using FabricJS canvas. For a test I created simple SVG shapes and add them to a canvas. I wand to download them as a .png and for that I use a button.

I use the arrow-function thing instead of .bind() for the method.

The following code is the part that creates the png and downloads it. It works in Chrome but not in Firefox.

```
import React from 'react';
import {fabric} from 'fabric';
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';


class FabricCanvas extends React.Component{

//Code for adding elements to canvas omitted

    saveToCanvas = () => {

        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = this.the_canvas.toDataURL({format: 'png'});
        link.download = "avatar.png";
        link.click();

    }

    render(){

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <canvas id='main-canvas'>
                </canvas>
                <Button className='large success' onClick={this.saveToCanvas} >
                    Download
                </Button>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any console errors?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo none concerning this function.

Comment: Possibly related to how `toDataURL` works on firefox. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32326943/canvas-todataurlimage-png-not-working-properly-in-firefox

Comment: @Jackyef I don't understand these answers how they apply to my issue. Can you please explain? I am not putting a data base64 into a img tag but want to give a download