# Async checking image width and height and if they are OK, preview image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check width and height from an input file's images and check if they are at least equal than specific dimension (w:300px, h:300px).

I have this check:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var fileUpload = document.getElementById("inputFileID");
    fileUpload.onchange = function () {
        if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
            var dvPreview = document.getElementById("divToShowThumbs");
            dvPreview.innerHTML = "";
            var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.jpg|.jpeg|.gif|.png|.bmp)$/;
            for (var i = 0; i < fileUpload.files.length; i++) {
                var file = fileUpload.files[i];
                if (regex.test(file.name.toLowerCase())) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        var img = document.createElement("IMG");
                        img.src = e.target.result;
                        dvPreview.appendChild(img);
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                } else {
                    alert(file.name + " is not a valid image file.");
                    dvPreview.innerHTML = "";
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            alert("This browser does not support HTML5 FileReader.");
        }
    }
};
```

This works ok to preview each image. 
But when I try to use "IF - ELSE" using img.width, it returns 0 because it works in asynchronous way!

Any light about how can I solve this situation?
All I'm trying to do is read each image, check if they area 300px (height and width) and if Ok, create the preview!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help from this - [Getting width & height of an image with filereader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491193/getting-width-height-of-an-image-with-filereader) . And here is your modified script.

```
        window.onload = function () {
        var fileUpload = document.getElementById("inputFileID");
        fileUpload.onchange = function () {
            if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                var dvPreview = document.getElementById("divToShowThumbs");
                dvPreview.innerHTML = "";
                var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.jpg|.jpeg|.gif|.png|.bmp)$/;
                for (var i = 0; i < fileUpload.files.length; i++) {
                    var file = fileUpload.files[i];
                    if (regex.test(file.name.toLowerCase())) {
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onload = function (e) {
                            var img = document.createElement("IMG");
                            img.src = e.target.result;                        

                            img.onload = function() {
                                // access image size here 
                                console.log(this.width + " " + this.height);

                                if(this.width <=300 && this.height <=300 )  {
                                    dvPreview.appendChild(img);
                                }
                                else {
                                    alert("too big an image!");
                                }
                            };

                        };
                        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                    } else {
                        alert(file.name + " is not a valid image file.");
                        dvPreview.innerHTML = "";
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                alert("This browser does not support HTML5 FileReader.");
            }
        };
    };
```