# How can i get image height and image width with FileReader and VueJs?

Tags: vue.js, filereader

I have an input type file

```
<input type="file" class="userUploadButton" name="image" accept="image/*" on-change={this.setImage}/>
```

and Vue - method "setImage"

```
    setImage(e){
        const file = e.target.files[0];

        if (!file.type.includes('image/')) {

            Vue.swal({
                title: 'Error!',
                text: 'This is no image',
                type: 'error',
            });

            return;
        }

        if(typeof FileReader === 'function'){

            const reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = (event) => {
                this.imgSrc = event.target.result;
                this.$refs.cropper.replace(event.target.result);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        }else{

            Vue.swal({
                title: 'Error',
                text: 'Your browser does not support FileReader API',
                type: 'error',
            });

        }

    },
```

In the moment when user upload an image, I have to check width and height of this image and stop uploading (or delete the image)

Comment: you mean need to check size?

Comment: i have to check image width and image height (px)

Comment: okay but the file is just a file, you need to create an image and then u will able to get image width and height

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting width & height of an image with filereader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491193/getting-width-height-of-an-image-with-filereader)

Comment: thanks. this link helped me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, the file is just a file, you need to create an image using `new Image()` from the file source.

Please check example to [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4N6D9/1/) and the same type of question to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903854/check-image-width-and-height-before-upload-with-javascript).

Use the following source code

```
   var width, height;

   var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

   img = new Image();

   img.onload = function() {
       // here you got the width and height
       width = this.width;
       height = this.height;
   };

   img.onerror = function() {
       alert( "not a valid file: " + file.type);
   };

   img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

Hopes this will help you!!