# Get width/height of uploaded by vue-upload-component image

Tags: vuejs2

Looking how vue-upload-component works (https://lian-yue.github.io/vue-upload-component/#/documents) on events when 
file is uploaded I see structure of avatarFiles array with uploaded file:

```
            <file-upload
                    ref="upload"
                    v-model="avatarFiles"
                    post-action="/post.method"
                    put-action="/put.method"
                    @input-file="inputFile"
                    @input-filter="inputFilter"
                    :multiple="false"
                    class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm"
            >
                Upload avatar
            </file-upload>
```

I do not see width/height of any uploaded file. If there is a way to add this info too?
Or some other vuejs way to get width/height of any uploaded file ?

vuejs 2.6

I try to check event when image is uploaded with:

**MODIFIED :**

```
watch:{
    avatarFiles(file){
        console.log("-1 avatarFiles file::")
        console.log( file )

        var image = new FileReader();
        console.log("-2 avatarFiles image::")
        console.log( image )
        image.onload = () => {
            console.log("-3 avatarFiles file::")
            console.log( file )
            console.log(`the image dimensions are ${img.width}x${img.height}`);
        }
    }

},
```

But image.onload is not triggered and in console I see some error message:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7LMS.jpg

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to watch your `avatarFiles` model, then read file using `FileReader`.

example codes:

```
watch:{
   avatarFiles(file){
          var image = new FileReader();
          image.onload = () => {
           console.log(`the image dimensions are ${image.width}x${image.height}`);
          }
      }

    }
```

Comment: Please, look at MODIFIED

Comment: I update my codes above. I have mistaken in naming the variable in this part `${img.width}x${img.height}` it should be `${image.width}x${image.height}`

Comment: I have different issue actually : code inside of image.onload is not triggered at all.

Comment: Kenneth, also are in your code file and image 2 different variables ? Is it correct. I suppose that must be 1 var ?

Comment: I uploaded this example live. Please, take a look at http://hostels2.my-demo-apps.tk/customer-register :
when image on 3rd tab is selected event is triggered.

But I see that onload is not triggered and error in method : https://imgur.com/a/oGZjJdc

Comment: Hopes it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49004162/how-can-i-get-image-height-and-image-width-with-filereader-and-vuejs